# On a Travis-CI build, how to only invoke SonarQube on master branch

Tags: sonarqube, travis-ci

As I only have the free CE account on SonarQube.com (SQ), I can not let it build any branch other then `master`.
How do I setup my `.travis.yml` so it triggers SQ only when building the `master` branch, but still builds other branches (just without triggering SQ)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Medling with the `script` part in `.travis.yml` works for me.

The **important part** is:

```
script:
  - cmdExtra=""; if [ $TRAVIS_BRANCH = "master" ]; then cmdExtra="<your-sonar-trigger-here>"; fi; <your-cmd-here> $cmdExtra
```

This is a complete example for a Maven based Java project:

```
language: java
sudo: false # faster builds

addons:
  sonarcloud:
    organization: "myOrganizationId"
    token:
      secure: "134f51f3451f3451ffe12f3124123123123123123123"

jdk:
  - openjdk8

script:
# NOTE JaCoCo is used to have code coverage, the agent has to be activated
# NOTE The SonarCube Community Edition (free plan) only supports branch "master".
  - cmdExtra=""; if [ $TRAVIS_BRANCH = "master" ]; then cmdExtra="sonar:sonar"; fi; mvn clean org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:prepare-agent package $cmdExtra

cache:
  directories:
    - '$HOME/.m2/repository'
    - '$HOME/.sonar/cache'
```